# Exchange SSL certificate via CLI in Plesk

Tags: ssl, command-line-interface, plesk, lets-encrypt

I'm generating SSL certificates with Let's Encrypt. It works fine, I have the CSR, the key and the certificate chain including the intermediate certificate for those browsers which don't know Let's Encrypt Certificate Authority yet. When creating a new certificate in Plesk (12), I copy-and-paste the given data, click on apply, apply the created certificate to the domain and it works as expected. Testing with `openssl` says

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect mydomain.com:443 -servername mydomain.com
<snip>
Certificate chain
0 s:/CN=www.mydomain.com
  i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
  i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
2 s:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
  i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
</snip>
```

Now, three month later, I have to re-issue those certificates. As I want to automate it, I want to use a CLI solution, like Plesk offers:

```
plesk bin certificate \
-u mycertificatename \
-domain mydomain.com \
-cert-file mynewcert.crt \
-key-file mykey.key
```

The problem: The certificate gets updated and is shown as expected in Plesk, but the intermediate certificate doesn't show up when testing with `openssl`:

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=www.mydomain.com
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
```

Any ideas? Did I forget to restart any service? Or any (un)documented feature?

Comment: Could you please share which browsers are don't know about Let's Encrypt CA ?

Comment: Could you please also share intermediate certificate which you are trying to add into chain?

Comment: Not specifically browsers, but DAVdroid and Ubuntu Calendar show a self-signed certificate or "The signing certificate authority is not known". The intermediate certificate is a `ca.cert` constisting of the [Let's Encrypt x3 cross-signed certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/certs/lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.pem.txt) and the [IdenTrust-DST-Root-CA-X3 certificate](https://www.identrust.com/certificates/trustid/root-download-x3.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use option

```
-cacert-file       <path>          CA certificate file
```

with path to CA file which containts all intermediate certificates